# finding and clicking button with Selenium by Onclick

Tags: javascript, selenium, button, selenium-webdriver

```
<div align="right" class="content-jumpmenu" id="searchDiv0">
<select name="menu1" id="menu1">
<input onclick="MM_jumpMenuGo('menu1','window','/ccmadmin', 1)" type="button" value="Go"/>
```

I need to click on the `Onclick=MM_JumpMenuGo` button. I tried:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Go")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='button'][value='Go']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#MM_jumpMenuGo)")).click();
```

None of these worked. I only need to press that button in Selenium. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: please format your code

Answer (score 1):

Your second selector actually looks correct. You can though omit the single quotes:

```
input[type=button][value=Go]
```

The selector, in general, is rather broad and can easily match a different element on a page.

Here are the alternative selectors:

```
div.content-jumpmenu input[type=button][value=Go]
select#menu1 input[type=button][value=Go]
input[onclick^=MM_jumpMenuGo]
```

The last one is searching for an `input` element with `onclick` attribute value to *start with* `MM_jumpMenuGo`.

---

And, since this is a "jump menu", it is probably activated with some action - a click or mouse over the menu itself. You may also miss this step.

---

There could be some animations or delays in showing the menu. Explicit wait may also be needed:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
WebElement goButton = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("input[onclick^=MM_jumpMenuGo]")));
goButton.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;                
js.ExecuteScript("MM_JumpMenuGo");
```